# Unable to create table in MySql in Yii installation

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am currently installing Yii framework using composer. There is step in which I have to create table in MySQL. They provided query for that:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_user (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);
```

But this query is giving error in table creation as follows:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTOINCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(128) N' at line 2
```

How to come out from this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is not problem regarding Yii framework. It is simple mysql query syntex error
right query is

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl_user (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
  );
```

Your query is almost right except AUTOINCREMENT. It will be AUTO_INCREMENT

Hope it will help you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

First, Welcome on Stack overflow. Your MySQL query is wrong. It should be

> AUTO_INCREMENT

Your query must be

```
  CREATE TABLE tbl_user (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
  );
```

Comment: In installation It is asking for Auth token, please help me. From where I can get this token?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/kz4egw/composer-install-github-rate-limiting-work-around

Comment: Thank you for your help in query. I got token from GitHub.